# Solr retreiving a range of queries

Tags: python, python-2.7, solr

```
url_path='https://v3v10.vitechinc.com/solr/v_us_participant/select?indent=on&q=*:*&fq=id:1&wt=json'
request = urllib2.Request(url_path)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
participant_data = response.read()
participant_data_metadata = json.loads(participant_data)['response']['docs']

for index in range(len(participant_data_metadata)):
    for key in participant_data_metadata[index]:
        print key ,':', (participant_data_metadata[index][key])
```

I have the following code which fetches the data where id =1 using solr query.

If i change the url path to retreive first 10 records like:

url_path='https://v3v10.vitechinc.com/solr/v_us_participant/select?indent=on&q=*:*&fq=id:[1 TO 10]&wt=json'

which should retrive records where ids are from 1 to 10 , ~10 rows , but instead its throwing error. `enter code here`

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

We can use something like below , but it will gives records with id =1 and 10 not the numbers in between
url_path='https://v3v10.vitechinc.com/solr/v_us_participant/select?indent=on&q=id:[1%20TO%2010]&wt=json'

Answer (score 0):

If you're only getting documents with values 1 and 10 in the id field for `id:[1 TO 10]` - the type of the field is probably string and not integer. If you have a string field it'll compare the tokens to your values as a sorted alphabetical list, where 1 and 10 will appear right after each other.

Change the field type to a int based field, reindex and then make the range query as you've already did, and you should get the documents with 1-10 in the id field. (i.e. 10 documents).

Comment: if its a string field how do we do it without converting into int . I understand for string it works like a matching expression and retrieves the records. @MatsLindh

Comment: You can't really do it for strings, as they don't sort in the same way as ints. If you _really_ can't change the field (why not? you probably can - by creating an extra field if necessary), you can prefix each number with zeroes to make it sort correctly. I.e. 000001, 000002, 000010, etc.